# Automatic do not disturb on second calendar

Tags: 7.0-nougat, calendar, 8.0-oreo, do-not-disturb

I've got multiple calendars on my google account, like one for family stuff, one that I use for shared events with my girlfriend, one for uni etc. I tried to set up my devices running android 7.1 and 8.0 to use automatic do-not-disturb rules so that it only activates silent mode while I am at university, but when I try to select the calendar I can only choose between "'s calendar" and "any calendar" (note that I use german android, so the options might not be called exactly this in english). Is there any way to select only my uni "sub-calendar", preferably without using apps like tasker?

Thanks in advance!